# WAR web app redeploying dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I'm new to Java. Having some trouble deploying a web app.

I have an EJB project which I deploy on Glassfish (4.1).
I also have a second, JSF WEB application that I deploy to the same server. 
Though I am making it with the consideration that it will be deployed to a separate server, so it creates it's own InitialContext and so on to access the EJBs.

The web application depends on the EJB project. The dependency is declared in the pom of the web app.
When deploying the web app it also tries to deploy the EJBs from the other project for some reason. 
That fails with errors like `javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException` because the EJBs are already deployed separately on this server.

How can this be fixed, so the EJB dependencies from the WEB app wouldn't be attempted to be deployed?

**Update**: the solution needed refactoring, so the EJBs wouldn't be depended on.

```
            Original        

   Project A                 WEB app
 ________________         ____________
| + EJBs         |<------| WEB stuff  |
| + Domain cl.   |        ------------
| + Remote intf. |
 ----------------

===========================================
            Refactored

  _______        ____________
 |  EJBs |----->| Domain cl. |
  -------        ------------
     |                  ^
     |                  |
     |                  |
     v                  |   WEB app
  ______________       ____________
 | Remote intf. | <---| Web stuff  |
  --------------       ------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the dependency a `scope` of `provided`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.some.id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>ear</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This means that at runtime, the dependency will be provided by the container.

see maven doc:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: That actually lets me deploy to the same server. Thanks.

Now when I try to deploy to another server, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` from the WEB app. 
I could declare the EJB dependency back to the `compile` scope, but then the EJBs would get deployed too and they're not needed on the other server.
Is there a way to prevent the EJB dependencies from getting deployed, but including the classes? The EJBs are always retrieved remotely.

Comment: The way it sounds to me, you need to set up different maven profiles for when you are deploying to the same server and another one for when you deploying to separate servers. You then set the dependency with the required scope for the relevant profile

Comment: I think I found the problem. The EJB project had the EJBs, domain classes and remote interfaces in one project. I broke it up. The web app only depends on the remote interfaces and the domain classes. Updated question with an ascii uml.